# Photoshop - Is there a way to re-link a file to the same size?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to add two images to my photoshop document. The images are different but I want them to be the same size in the document. The images have the same aspect ratio but one is slightly bigger than the other, which seems to be my problem.

What I've tried to do is this:
1. Place linked. Place one image. Size it the way I want.
2. Copy the image/layer and move this to the position I want. Size does not change.
3. I now have two identical images. So I right click one one and go to 'replace contents' or 'relink' and I select the other, slightly bigger image.
When I do this, the second image is imported at it's size rather than the fize I already fixed.

It's not a big deal thing, I can always fix this as I go along, but I feel like there has to be a way to do this quickly and simply. I know Illustrator has this feature where I can just replace contents and keep sizing constraints. Does PS have a way?

Edit: Oops, just realized there was a graphic design board. I saw someone else post photoshop Q's here, so I assumed there wasn't one. I'm going to repost there/

Thanks,

Comment: You could always open the images separately, change the image size through photoshop's dialog boxes, save as a separate working .psd, and then open to edit?

Comment: Transform [Cmd/T on Mac, presumably Ctrl/T Windows]